# complete bootstrap website is not working on iOS devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

This is link to my website I just developed "www.warmfarewells.org", It works on all other devices than iOS devices. Can any body please help me with that? It opens the landing page, but is not clickable.

Comment: Not the source of your problem but you have a syntax error at line 928 where you have 2 open <script> tags.

Comment: thank you. I tried, all other pages were already working, but the landing page is still not clickable on iOS devices.

Answer (score 0):

When I use web inspector with Safari (on a Mac) I'm seeing errors which I don't see with Chrome web inspector, see attached screenshot. These *may* be related to the home page carousel.

Are you able to temporarilly remove this JS from the home page and check if it makes a difference on iOS?
[image]